# как получить root (linux) права с загрузочной флешки?

Tags: linux

как получить root (linux) права с загрузочной флешки?

Comment: Очевидно, зависит от того, что и как у вас на этой флешке настроено

Comment: `sudo -i`, `su`?

Comment: @don Rumata спасибо,sudo -i работает.